# Samsung Galaxy note 3 SM-N9005 cannot boot due to Power down

Tags: samsung-galaxy-note-3

I have Samsung galaxy note 3 SM-N9005 and I wanted to make hard reset but I accidental did Power down. And now, my phone does not fully switch on. When I turn on the phone it stops at the Samsung sign. I waited for several minutes but nothing further happened.

Comment: Not sure if Galaxt note 3 comes with an unlocked bootloader by default, but try booting into Recovery, and doing something like a re-install (stock recovery should do in that case). You could technically go to download mode and install a custom recovery, but that voids warranty

Comment: when I switch on Adroid system recovery it offers me:
1.reboot system now
2.apply update from ADB
3.APPLY UPDATE FROM EXTERNAL SORAGE 4.apply update from cache 5.wipe data/factory reset 6.wipe cache partition 7.reboot to bootloader 8.Power down 9.voew recoveru logs 10.Enable cp logging 11.Disable cp logging

Comment: Did you mean you accidentally turned off the phone while doing hard reset?

Comment: I took the phone for repair and found out the  problem,they said that the need to reinstall the entire phone again.

Answer (score 0):

The OP stated (in a comment),

> I took the phone for repair and found out the problem, they said that they need to reinstall the entire phone again.